# Filter out declined events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-graph-api

I need to use microsoft graph api, more in detail the calendar one, to retrieve some events of the users (up to 1000 entries).
I need to filter out the events that the user have declined.
That information is stored in the `assignee` resource, or conveniently in the 'responseStatus' property.

The issue that I'm having is that anytime I try to retrieve the assignee resource, the query takes 10x time to perform (from 1.2s without the assignees to 12-14s with).
(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?select=id,subject,start,end,sensitivity,assignee&top=1000`)

So i've tried to get the responseStatus instead and...guess what, the performance are always 10x worst (`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?select=id,subject,start,end,sensitivity,responseStatus&top=1000`)

I've then decided to try to filter them directly (`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?select=id,subject,start,end,sensitivity,responseStatus&top=1000&filter=responseStatus/response ne 'declined'`) but I receive an error message stating that "The property 'responseStatus' does not support filtering."

And I'm having an hard time filtering the assignee resource.

So...is there a simple way to filter declined events without having such performance issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the extended property pidlidresponsestatus  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidresponsestatus-canonical-property to filter those out eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location,responsestatus&$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep:ep/id eq 'Integer {00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8218' and cast(ep/value, Edm.Int32) ne 4)
```

Comment: Thanks, really. I would have never know that it was possible to write a filter in that way without your help!